# Java: Automatic way to encapsulate a library

Tags: java, eclipse, encapsulation, rcp

I have the following scenario: I am using a very big external library in my Eclipse RCP  application for a specific purpose.

At this point in time I am not sure if I may not have to replace this library in the future to another one (because it does not provide the necessary functionality or something like that). Also I have users using this library from day one so I would like to encapsulate the library, giving me at least a chance of changing the library in the future without the user noticing or having to change anything in their code.

Is there a simple way to encapsulate a whole library in some automated fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the part of the library's interface you are actually using is completely trivial, or standardized the way JSF or JAX-B are (in which case you don't need encapsulation) this is a completely wasted effort.

I can guarantee that if you have to switch to a different library, the encapsulation would prove worthless because the other library has different underlying concepts and usage patters that cannot be made to fit the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible, since the syntax and semantics of the library might be unique to some extent.

Sure, you could create proxies for all the classes and provide those, but that might require quite some work (writing a framework that scans the library) and that wouldn't guarantee you that exchanging the library would be easy.

Imagine the replacement would provide different methods and even use different semantics (to some extent). What if methods/fields etc. were missing in the replacement?

The best way to handle that would be to write an explicit wrapper and make the users use only that wrapper. This way you could restrict the API to the core concepts that are really needed. This still might not provide a good enough encapsulation however, based on what the library actually does.

*Example*:

For 3D programming you could use OpenGL or Direct3D. Both have somewhat different APIs but use the same core concepts. Thus you could create a wrapper for them that provides a unified API. That wrapper might then have to convert some data etc. (like making column-oriented matrics row-oriented and vice versa) but since the core concepts are the same, that should be doable.

However, you'd need to stick to the core concepts and couldn't use additional features. For example, Direct3D would also provide some more highlevel API (Direct3DX) which isn't provided by OpenGL.